# Tectia SSH bash shell

Tags: ssh

I have Tectia SSH 6.4.15 installed on a Windows server.  When I ssh to that server, I got a Windows shell.

> Microsoft Windows [Version 6.3.9600] (c) 2013 Microsoft Corporation.
>   All rights reserved.
>
> C:\Users\foo>

Is it possible to get a bash shell (like Cygwin)?

Comment: ServerFault.com is probably the site (or the droids) you're looking for.  It's never too late to read [tour] and [ask]

Answer (score 0):

Server Fault is probably a better place to ask this question, but the answer is no for Tectia on windows, not without changing the default shell for windows.

It would be better to use the SSH server in Cygwin instead, I assume you have it installed because you mentioned it.  This would allow you to use the cygwin bash shell when you SSH to the machine.

FYI:
I worked as a developer (I don't work there anymore) for Tectia.